# how to remove bold words from python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I have a docx that I need to preprocess using spaCy. I need to remove all words that appear in bold in the document.

I tried the following:

```
def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
p = paragraph._element
p.getparent().remove(p)
p._p = p._element = None


length = len(document.paragraphs)
for i in range(0,length):
  for j in range(0,len(document.paragraphs[i].runs)):
     if document.paragraphs[i].runs[j].bold == True:
        delete_paragraph(document.paragraphs[i])
        length = length-1
        continue
document.save("/home/nikita/Desktop/Internship/new topic_mod/AXIS new.docx")
```

But I get the following error:

```
IndexError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-d144bd42e95e> in <module>()
  3     #print(document.paragraphs[i].text)
  4     for j in range(0,len(document.paragraphs[i].runs)):
----> 5         if document.paragraphs[i].runs[j].bold == True:
  6             delete_paragraph(document.paragraphs[i])
  7             length = length-1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I cannot figure out why its out of range.
How can I remove bold words from a python-docx ?

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple probable reasons:

1. You need to break (not `continue`) out of your inner loop once you've deleted the paragraph, otherwise you try to delete the same paragraph multiple times if it has more than one bold run.

   ```
   for j in range(0,len(document.paragraphs[i].runs)):
       if document.paragraphs[i].runs[j].bold == True:
           delete_paragraph(document.paragraphs[i])
           length = length-1
           break
   ```
2. Your list of paragraphs is getting shorter each time you delete one, which changes the index of each paragraph that follows. If you traverse the paragraphs from bottom to top, that won't be a problem. Also, you can ditch all that (i, j) index management; Python rarely needs that.

   ```
   for paragraph in reversed(list(document.paragraphs)):
       for run in paragraph.runs:
           if run.bold:
               delete_paragraph(paragraph)
               break
   ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange Kiera. Don't neglect to accept the answer if it answered your question. That's how respondents are rewarded for taking the time to answer your question :)

Comment: Thank you :) I did accept your answer ( multiple times ) but since I am relatively new here and still learning , I don't have the required number of reputations. So when I accept it , it says :
"Thanks for the feedback. Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score" :( :(

Comment: The checkmark icon is the one for accepting. The arrow keys vote up and down and don't activate right away :)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that! Thanks :)